# How to download a file accepting license using powershell

Tags: powershell, wget, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to download package from the below link using powershell.
https://www.tenable.com/downloads/nessus-agents
i do not have direct link for these package also when i click on download it ask to agree. I was able to do it on Linux using command shown below. Kindly advise how can i do it in windows.

```
"wget  --no-check-certificate --post-data='accept="I accept the terms of this license"&x=""&sid=5mcia8gchg28attkc9oarah153&p=NessusAgent-7.4.2-amzn.x86_64.rpm' 'https://www.tenable.com/downloads/nessus-agents' -O NessusAgent-7.4.2-amzn.x86_64.rpm"
```

could not find anything tried option with invoke-webrequest

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://www.tenable.com/downloads/nessus-agents'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a GET query string parameter that indicates acceptance.

Simply add `i_agree_to_tenable_license_agreement=true` to your query string parameters.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.tenable.com/downloads/api/v1/public/pages/nessus-agents/downloads/9762/download?i_agree_to_tenable_license_agreement=true' -OutFile 'NessusAgent-7.4.2-x64.msi'
```

You can easily get the IDs of the other files from their API endpoint like so:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://www.tenable.com/downloads/api/v1/public/pages/nessus-agents' | ConvertFrom-Json).downloads | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua. Something new for me. btw how did you get the below URL
https://www.tenable.com/downloads/api/v1/public/pages/nessus-agents

Comment: @Mandy I manually downloaded the file while monitoring the `Network` tab in the browser's developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar syntax in Powershell, but it's just downloading a file with contents "OK".

```
$body = 'accept="I accept the terms of this license"&x=""&sid=5mcia8gchg28attkc9oarah153&p=NessusAgent-7.4.2-amzn.x86_64.rpm' 
$uri = 'https://www.tenable.com/downloads/nessus-agents'
$resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Body $body -Uri $uri -OutFile .\NessusAgent-7.4.2-amzn.x86_64.rpm
```

Maybe the "sid" variable needs to change per request.